# How to convert quotes(',") from special char to general with other tags remaining special?

Tags: php, html, tags

In my string I have quotes`(',")` and `< tags >` . I used

```
htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES);
```

to convert only the single and double quote to general text . But unfortunately it is also converting tags `< ,  >` . For this reason even I have

```
strip_tags("$desc","< b >< font >< i >< u >< br >");
```

Those allowed tags are also displaying as general `< and >` sign not working as html tags .

In conclude , I want to display single and double quote as regular text and allowed tags working as html does.

Thank You.

Comment: if they are in string try:`str_replace("'","",$desc)` it will remove all `'`.

Comment: I don't want to remove it .I want them work as general text not as special characters.

Comment: So why don't you replace ' to \'

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you run strip_tags() before  htmlspecialchars() ?

sample:

```
<?php
$input = '<b>allowed tag</b> " <font>not allowed tag</font>';

// XXX
$tmp = htmlspecialchars($input, ENT_QUOTES);
$result = strip_tags($tmp, '<b>');
var_dump($result);
// string(78) "&lt;b&gt;allowed tag&lt;/b&gt; &quot; &lt;font&gt;not allowed tag&lt;/font&gt;"

// Improved
$tmp = strip_tags($input, '<b>');
$result = htmlspecialchars($tmp, ENT_QUOTES);
var_dump($result);
// string(53) "&lt;b&gt;allowed tag&lt;/b&gt; &quot; not allowed tag"
```